# Region of convergence of a series of finite terms

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Say I want to expand 
\begin{equation}
\frac{z^3}{(z+i)^2}
\end{equation}
about $z=-i$. The answer is straightforward, I get a few terms
\begin{equation}
\frac{i}{(z+i)^2} - \frac3{z+i}- 3i +(z+i).
\end{equation}
I am being asked about the region of convergence of these terms. I have thought of two different solutions:

1. There is no region of convergence, this is only relevant for a power series and this isn't one.
2. The series (as much as one can call it) converges to itself.

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: Actually I don't understand the meaning of "region of convergence", since there is no power series here. I would say that the region of convergence is $\Bbb{C} \setminus \{ -i \}$

Comment: @Crostul Exactly my thoughts. (See solution 1.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Laurent series. It's just the case that most of the terms vanish. The "series" converges for all $z \neq -i$.

Comment: Guess I'll go with this one... Somehow, I always thought that a Laurent series had to have an infinite amount of terms...

Comment: Nah, coefficients can be zero. Polynomials are their own Mclaurin series for example.